# Writing Integral as a Differantial equation.

Tags: calculus

I was trying to calculate the Mass M between two spheres and I write an integral in the form of

$$M=\rho\int_{R_0}^R 4\pi R^2dR$$

Can I write it like this

$$dM=\rho (4\pi R^2)dR$$

The thing that bugs me is the integral boundries can I just make them disappear ? Also what it means R and dR here ?

Comment: yes, it is correct, however you must write $dr$ or something different inside the integral, to distinguish from $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion between variables and limits of integration it is better the notation:
$$M=\rho\int_{R_0}^R 4\pi r^2dr$$

and from this, as a consequence of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), we have:

$$
\frac{dM}{dR}=\rho 4 \pi R^2 
$$

and it is an usual convection to write, from this,
$$
dM=\rho 4 \pi R^2  dR
$$

Comment: Geometrically is there a meaning in $dr$ or $r$ here ? Or its just a notation. I have some other equations that I need to use R so its confusing

Comment: It seems like the information is lost about $R$ and $R_0$ and thats not good for me ..

Comment: Well yes, but it seems wrong I guess